# How to Navigate to another view by a button click

Tags: typescript, aurelia

How to navigate toanother view using a button click in Aurelia ?

My Code

```
 <button class="btn btn-success " click.delegate="save()" >New item</button>
```

TS

```
   configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router){
    config.title = 'Contacts';
    config.options.pushState = true;
    config.options.root = '/';
    config.map([
      { route: '',   moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('no-selection'),   title: 'Select' },
     { route: 'contacts/:id',  moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('contact-detail'), name:'contacts' },

     { route: 'new', moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('new-contact-detail'),    nav: true }
]);

this.router = router;
 }

save() {
console.log("Button Clicked");
this.router.navigateToRoute('new');


  }
```

Comment: Hi, It is not totally clear what you are trying to do. Can you provide access to your code in github or a sandbox so we are able to help? Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

`navigateToRoute` is used with the route *name* as parameter, you are supplying it with a *route*

give your 'new' route a name and use `navigateToRoute`, or use `navigate('new')` as that method takes the route as a parameter instead of the name